# Elasticsearch different behaviour on test server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

My elasticsearch is currently giving different results on different environments even though I'm doing the same search.
It works fine in development on my localhost, however it doesn't work on my test server (doesn't give expected records, yes I do have the database seeded).

Far as I understand what this should do is check whether it finds a hit on one of the three matches, and if it does return all the hits.

I'm running Windows 10, just using `rails s`.

The server is running Ubuntu 16, using nginx and unicorn.

Here's my mapping: (note: I'm not completely sure whether the analyzer does anything but it shouldn't matter)

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
  mappings dynamic: 'true' do
    indexes :reportdate, type: 'date'
    indexes :client do
      indexes :id
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'dutch'
    end
    indexes :animal do
      indexes :id
      indexes :species, analyzer: 'dutch'
      indexes :other_species, analyzer: 'dutch'
      indexes :chip_code
    end
    indexes :locations do
      indexes :id
      indexes :street, analyzer: 'dutch'
      indexes :city, analyzer: 'dutch'
      indexes :postalcode
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my search:

```
__elasticsearch__.search({
  sort: [
    { reportdate: { order: "desc" }},
    "_score"
  ],
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        { multi_match: {
          query: query,
          type: "phrase_prefix",
          fields: [ "other_species", "name"]
        }},
        { prefix: {
          chip_code: query
        }},
        { match_phrase: {
          "_all": {
            query: query,
            fuzziness: "AUTO"
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

EDIT #1: Note: I'm fairly new to ruby on rails, started about 2 weeks ago, doing maintenance work on an old project and they also requested a search function.

Comment: Is your test server drawing off the same db or a different db that is seeded than your localhost?  Also, analyzers change the way ElasticSearch indexes and tokenizes documents so make sure you're running the same setup between the two servers or results will vary greatly.

Comment: They're different databases, they're seeded the same though. Anyways, just found out that it's probably rails caching files and not using updated files for some reason. Thanks for the comment either way, I'm just going to delete this question and reopen another to avoid confusion.  (plus it doesn't seem to have much to do with elasticsearch)

Comment: Nevermind, had been looking through other answers with that same premise, and it did seem to be caching files but fixed that and this problem still persists.

Comment: A couple of things to check. Are the number of docs in all indices the same? You can do an empty search and see the numhits. localhost:9200/index_name/_search.  Is the "reportdate" field by any chance an auto generated timestamp during indexing? Since you are doing a sort on this field, the results might vary on different servers.

Comment: Did a couple checks as requested. The mapping's are exactly the same (as expected). @jay The number of docs in the indices are not the same since over time extra test records were added. Yes the reportdate is an automatically generated field, however I'm not sure why this would matter (except for the sorting order of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that I was using foreign tables (well, kinda) and nested mapping (probably this).

Here's the updated code that works on both production and locally:

```
__elasticsearch__.search({
  sort: [
    { reportdate: { order: "desc" }},
    "_score"
  ],
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        { multi_match: {
          query: query,
          type: "phrase_prefix",
          fields: [ "animal.other_species", "client.name"]
        }},
        { prefix: {
          "animal.chip_code": query
        }},
        { match_phrase: {
          "_all": {
            query: query,
            fuzziness: "AUTO"
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Not sure why it doesn't need the animal and client parents preappended to work locally whilst it does need them on my testing server. However this works on both this way.